Determining an optimal level of aggregation that balances accuracy and granularity
I am looking for ideas for aggregating prediction outcomes in a way that maximizes the number of classes while minimizing classification error.
As a motivating example, say I'm working on a prediction task to classify songs by genre and there are 6 genres (from the target column below):



Genre (Broad)
Genre (Target)




Pop
Indie pop


Pop
Hyperpop


Pop
K-Pop


Rock
Alt rock


Rock
Classic rock


Rock
Hard rock



The model has 100% accuracy identifying the first 4 categories (indie pop, hyperpop, k-pop, alt rock) but misclassifies around ~50% of hard rock songs as classic rock and ~20% of classic rock songs as hard rock.
Based on this, one could imagine aggregating the target genre in a few ways which would reduce the classification error. E.g.

2 classes: Pop, rock
4 classes: Indie pop, hyperpop, K-pop, rock
5 classes: Indie pop, hyperpop, K-pop, alt rock, other rock

In this case, I'd want to aggregate the target genres to those 5 classes, keeping as many categories as I can while maintaining the same level of accuracy.
To find the ideal aggregation structure, I could permute over all possible aggregations and calculate the MSE. However, this would not be computationally feasible given the number of classes I'm working with. So, I was wondering if there is some relevant literature that I can read to better understand how to tackle this problem or if anyone has ideas.

There are a couple of votes to close this as a "programming request" but this question clearly isn't asking for code, but rather an algorithm/procedure (or just a literature pointer to the right area) that clumps sub-classes together in a reasonable way to keep the model's classifications more accurate/meaningful. I wonder whether this would have got a better response at https://datascience.stackexchange.com than here, but it strikes me as a fundamentally on-topic and practically interesting question.

Can I still post it on datascience.stackexchange.com? If so, should I delete the question from here?

I'd be tempted to give it a few more days, ironically being put on the review queue might gain the question some eyeballs. I've wondered something similar to this before but haven't seen another question quite like it. I wouldn't have phrased it in terms of maintaining 100% accuracy, but more about how to pick an appropriate level of granularity for category predictions given lower accuracy for narrower subcategories - still pretty close to the spirit of what you're asking. So I'm tempted to put a bounty on this question which might draw some attention, if you're happy to keep it here for now?

I agree with your point; maintaining 100% accuracy is definitely not the goal, if anything I'm trying to find a good balance between accuracy and granularity. My sense of the algorithm is it would maybe include a penalty for each aggregation so that a class is only sacrificed if it produces a meaningful gain in accuracy. In any case, I'll keep the question here for a few days!

@MattF. Yes, I think this is definitely something a good answer will have to address - if you're going to make a trade-off that implies you have some way of valuing accuracy vs granularity, some kind of loss function say. I'm sure pointers in the literature to how this is commonly done would be useful. But what you do next is not obvious, if it's computationally infeasible to evaluate for every possible aggregation choice - I'd be surprised if this problem hadn't been considered before

I think @mle_in_paris would benefit from changing the question title to match the comment, "that would balance accuracy and granularity" or similar, instead of "that would minimize prediction error" - leaving the current title is just asking for the smart-ass answer "you minimise prediction error by aggregating everything into the single category 'music' to ensure 0% error".

Thank you @Silverfish, I just did.

@MattF. Or alternatively, the main post could be more explicit about the metric of optimality being part of the question itself. Plenty of questions on this site are about trade-offs, and part of that is how we might balance a trade-off in some kind of principled manner - if the OP doesn't have a strong preconceived idea of how they want to work through a trade-off, I think it's absolutely "fair game" to ask what people in the field commonly do. I did read this as implicitly part of the question, but it wouldn't hurt to make it more explicit if that's the OP's intention.

@Silverfish For cases where hierarchy doesn't apply, see here

Thank you @MuhammedYunus, I thought this was very useful. Using the misclassification rates as a similarity measure is a great first step -- only thing is I would maybe opt for similarity[i,j]=average(error_counts[i,j],error_counts[j,i])?

I think average would work too, and the code would be a bit simpler. I opted for max because I felt it encoded my assumptions more strongly, but it's just one way of combining information.
